# Add a file to a jar using python zipfile

Tags: python, file, jar, addition, python-zipfile

I need to add a file to jar but when i run the program zipfile delete all file and add a file.
but i need the other files!

my code: (this is a test)

```
import zipfile
    
m= zipfile.ZipFile("test.jar","w")
m.write("test.jar","bgt.class")
m.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in *append* mode, using `a`:

```
m = zipfile.ZipFile("test.jar", "a")
```

You opened the file in `w` write mode, which clears the file before writing. From the [`zipfile.ZipFile()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile):

> The *mode* parameter should be `'r'` to read an existing file, **`'w'` to truncate and write a new file, or `'a'` to append to an existing file. If `mode` is `'a'` and file refers to an existing ZIP file, then additional files are added to it.**

Bold emphasis mine.